# Retrieving value from SQL Server Management Studio in asp.net ide

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, linq

I am getting all cell value from table from SQL Server Management Studio to asp.net 4.0 ide. But I don't know why but every value is automatically appended with 3 spaces. And I am not able to trim those values also. So I m not able to compare those values with values like password value from textbox. And I am using linq query and linq to sql dbml files. Can anyone tell me whats happening with me? and how to resolve this issue? Thanks.

Here is code:

```
      DataClasses1DataContext dj = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var pwd = from p in dj.USERs
                  where p.USER_NAME.ToLower().Trim() == _userName.Text.ToString().ToLower().Trim()
                  select new { p.PASSWORD };

        var utype = from u in dj.USERs
                    where u.USER_NAME.ToLower().Trim() == _userName.Text.ToString().ToLower().Trim()
                    select new { u.USER_TYPE };

    if (_password.Text.ToString() == pwd.ToString().Trim())
        //**in above line i m getting pwd.tostring() values to "admin    "
        //_password.text value "admin" .. so it fails to trim and hence compare.**
           {
                if (Session["username"] == null)
                {
                    Session["username"] = _userName.Text.ToString().ToLower();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _wrongDetails.Text = "Wrong UserName or Password Entered!";
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think in your table , column may have type char, which is of fixed length so spaces may be appended.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are storing your password as a `char` rather than a `varchar`.

However, storing passwords as plain text is bad practice. You should look to hash your stored passwords.